# How to talk to authorities to convince them to bicycle initiatives?

Tags: legal, downhill, xc

Since at least 1998 in unkempt, secluded place in Warsaw, PL,  [there](https://goo.gl/maps/JgW5PmvpFMx) was an unofficial [downhill track](https://youtu.be/RL379oKUTvk). Between the bushes some youngsters constructen on their own ramps etc. Between september/october this year users of that place decided to talk to the authorities to mark this track (at their own, private expense) and make its legal status clear.

Our authorities said not only: "No", but within single month wiped everything away, claiming that this is just a piece of rubbish, that is also unsafe, not compliant with local plan, entacted in 2000 (but that plan can be seen as "dead", within 16 years nothing has been constructed, there are wild trees, trodden paths, a lot of rubbish and one official pavement/stairs to the 1944 Warsaw Uprising monument). No will to consult, no will to discuss.

At present:
[image]

So how would you talk to authorities to gain at least no hostility against 
grassroots initiative?

Clarification: This place is an artificial hillock, made from the  post-WWII-rubble.
Since 2004 it's named to commemorate Warsaw Uprising, but its not any kind of graveyard or so.

Comment: Given the current political situation in Poland, and in light of the response you've just seen, my advice is to tread very carefully with an ear to the local politics. It's clear that if you were a senior member of PiS, or a relative, you could just do as you please. When the Minister for the Environment presides over it's destruction, and the *Law and Justice* government turns a blind eye to blatant attacks on protesters and starts arresting apposing politicians on pretext, a bicycle park has little hope, especially when they are anti-cycling.

Comment: @andy256 despite your diagnosis of national level political situation can be seen as true, it does (or should?) not apply to this case. Warsaw is ruled by the biggest opposition party, PO(which has good press here and abroad, but in real there is no qualitative difference between both, when comes to pro-society stuff). But I don't think it is really connected to politics, it's too low-level and depends on single person attitude

Comment: Yes, since posting the first comment, I realised that PO does hold Warszawa. So you should search out local bicycle advocacy groups. If you cannot find any then consider forming such a group, and at the same time try to find the right person to talk to. And try contacting Robert Biedron, President of Słupsk; he (as you may know) is a cyclist, and should have contacts in Warszawa, even though he's not PO. Good luck :-)

Comment: @andy256 ok, I see that your suggested answer is to knock higher in the political hierarchy, to be listened to at local level. The rest was done as you suggested, guys were represented by Warsaw Cycle Club (http://wkk.waw.pl/) It also attracted local media attention. Of course I know Robert Biedroń, I'm surprised that his fame came so far. I don't think local politicians would respect his opinion.

Comment: My thinking about Robert is that he would probably know who you should talk to, and might also give advice on how to approach those people to get best results. Since Tusk moved into the EU, Robert Biedroń is one of the few *sensible* politicians left in PL.

Comment: Hmm. From the information I have (it could be wrong) the hill you mention is a memorial to the Wawsaw Uprising. The reason the track was suddenly destroyed was because a different person became responsible for the city environment. And finally, the matter has been put before the police, who are seeking the perpetrators to issue fines. Hopefully my information is incorrect :-(

Comment: @andy256 yes it is kind of memorial, what I've written in question. It was named in 2004, it is not connected to uprising no more than other places in Warsaw (debris from Warsaw were stacked there to construct anti-flood embarkment in late 40s, but it turned out to be useles material, so was left as a trash hill). Also the Combatants were supporting bikers initiative.

Comment: @andy256 don't want to develop that plot, as it fits politics better. But I'm really surprised to consider Tusk and Biedroń "similar" when it comes to *sensibility*. And I guess it's too high (Tusk), he will not want to talk about such unimportant thing.

Comment: It's hard enough to keep the "authorities" from not instituting even more stupid rules, without any understanding of cycling.  An idiot legislator here is trying to require that cyclists get a license in order to use bike lanes on streets.

Comment: Now they announced that they're going to rebuild the track and the cyclists will be involved in planning. It looks like it is connected with hard times that ruling party encounters and it's aimed to improve polls.

Comment: @krzyski Great news - please add your own answer showing that and accept it.

Answer (score 1):

Your best recourse is find yourselves rich and influential sponsors to advocate for you.

Or purchase the land outright.

Or a combination of both.

Comment: Because a monument of Warsaw Uprising was set there several years ago, a "money on the table" option is not possible, it will never be for sale. It is public property, parks etc. does not require, should not require sponsorship....

Comment: @krzyski enough money and influence being bought to bear would make that problem disappear. Unfortunately you don't have either, so it behooves you to find sponsors that do. Or give up. By sponsors I mean advocates for your cause, rather than monetary help for you personally.